# django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "blog_post" already exists

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a blog using Django and anytime I run `manage.py migrate`, I get the error below:

```
(venv) (C:\Users\KOLAPO\Anaconda3) C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\shelteratyourcrossroads>manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, sessions, sites, taggit
Running migrations:
  Applying blog.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 335, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table "blog_post" already exists

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\shelteratyourcrossroads\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 96, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 295, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 112, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Programming\Websites\shelteratyourcrossroads\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 335, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "blog_post" already exists
```

Here's everything in my `models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, 
            self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    subtitle = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    # body = models.TextField()
    body = RichTextUploadingField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args=[
            self.publish.year, self.publish.strftime('%m'),
            self.publish.strftime('%d'), self.slug])

    objects = models.Manager() # default manager
    published = PublishedManager() # custom manager

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Profile for user {}'.format(self.user.username)

class Feedback(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="name of sender")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    message = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Feedback"

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name, "-", self.email)
```

I'm stuck on that error. How do I fix it please?

Comment: As the error says the table `blog_post` already exists and the migration tries to create the table.

Comment: If you don't have any important data in the database, just delete the file with the database (something like `db.sqlite3`) and start over.

Comment: But I'd like to keep the content of the database. If I delete the database file, I'm gonna have to start over again

Comment: My comment starts with **If**. Obviously it isn't a viable option in your case. Eventually you could dump the data, delete the database, run the migrations, and then load the data again. Somewhere you have messed something. Do `manage.py dbshell` and inspect the table `blog_post`. Does all columns correspond to the fields in the class `Post`. Check the entries in `django_migrations`. One thing is to find a solution that'll do it, another thing is to find the cause of the problem, learn from your own errors and prevent such issues in the future.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe faking the initial migration of blog app will help you. Try the following.

> `./manage.py migrate --fake blog 0001_initial`

Comment: What if the model has some changes that are not reflected in the DB, then this procedure is not suitable. reverting the Django migration will do the job.  `./manage.py migrate blog zero`  then do run the command `/manage.py migrate blog `

Comment: Note that `migrate blog zero` will drop any tables from the blog app, so is not suitable if you need to keep the data in those tables.

Answer (score 1):

Django 3.2

The following worked for me:
delete all the migration files, including the initial migration. Then perform:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time I see this kind of question I wondered: if the `model.py` is ok, why does no one suggests (in the answer) dropping the wrong table and - instead - almost everybody suggests deleting all migration files? It's overkill!

If `model.py` is proper and ok now, then you can always do two things:

1. **Edit** migration files - instead of deleting them. If this doesn't work, then:
2. With ***SQL shell***: drop a single (wrong) table by accessing it via **SQLite** or **PostgreSQL** - depending on the one that you are using. Also, you can *edit* and *update* it.

**Update:**

There are some cases when things get more tricky. If the problem is related to the foreign key that was added to the particular table in **SQLite**, then it's more difficult to solve the problem, than having the same issue but with **PostgreSQL**. The **SQLite** is lacking some very handy features like removing a column that has foreign keys. I had a few situations where the first error was related to some table that I needed to drop, but after that, another issue was with a foreign key. Because both problems were related to some model that had a **one-to-many** relation. That's why I recommend getting familiar with **PostgreSQL**. That will make it easier to solve this kind of situation without deleting a whole database.